# Cannot refer to a non-final variable timePicker inside an inner class defined in a different method.where is the inner class??

Tags: android, inner-classes

```
      public class MainActivity extends Activity {
 TimePicker timePicker;

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

   TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);

    //--Button view---
    Button btnOpen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSet);
    btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Time selected:" + 
                    timePicker.getCurrentHour() + 
                    ":" + timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       }
                 });
             }
           }




       somebody  explain me plz ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TimePicker timePicker;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);

//--Button view---
Button btnOpen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSet);
btnOpen.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() // <------- Inner class
{
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                "Time selected:" + 
                timePicker.getCurrentHour() + 
                ":" + timePicker.getCurrentMinute(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 });
```

You're creating an anonymous class that extends the abstract OnClickListenerClass by providing an onClick method.

To fix, declare timePicker as **final**.

```
final TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
```

Comment: but if i remove the TimePicker from the code TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker)findViewById(R.id.timePicker); timePicker.setIs24HourView(true); the code is working no need to declare as final...whats the matter..?will u explan me plz...?

Comment: Just add **final** in front of the declaration within your onCreate method. _Or_ remove the local declaration and use your member variable (also with the same name...timePicker).

Comment: You have two timePicker variables - a locally scoped one declared within **onCreate** and a member variable ("package" scoped because you didn't specify private or public - which is unimportant here) variant. Chances are, the **onClick** method of your **OnClickListener** instance is calling the member variable since it can't see **onCreate**'s local one.